# Get specific div when clicking button in php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, while-loop, onclick

I have a while loop spitting out multiple post which each has a div button called 'flag_btn', when clicked I am trying to show the corresponding div container for my form all being displayed from a PHP while loop -

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $post_id = $row['post_id'];
echo "
<div id='flag_btn'>flag </div>
<div id='flag_cont' style='display:none'>
    <form method='post' class='flag_form'>
        <input type='radio' name='flag_reason' value='off'>Its Offensive<br>
        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
</div>
";
```

Here is the jquery click event -

```
$('#flag_btn').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('#flag_cont').show(200);
});
```

But it doesn't work.. How can I get the click event to display just the flag_cont that corresponds to the post that was clicked?

*note: I didnt post the php while loop as I felt it was unnecessary..

Comment: Do you have multiple flag buttons with the same ID on a page? ID's are supposed to be UNIQUE, only one per page. Try changing that to a class instead: `$('.flag_btn').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.flag_cont').show(200);
});`

Comment: You should definitely include the php loop in your question.

Comment: Ok just added the while loop

Comment: @RyanD In this case, knowing the structure of the loop makes it available for others to form their answer to fit with your question, since you most likely need unique ID:s on your elements, or another solution which doesn't use ID:s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `next()` is better in this case.

I also replaced `id` on the "Buttons" with `class` so it will work for multiple "Buttons".

```js
$('.flag_btn').click(function() {
  $(this).next('#flag_cont').show(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='flag_btn'>flag1</div>
<div id='flag_cont' style='display:none'>
  <form method='post' class='flag_form'>
    <input type='radio' name='flag_reason' value='off'>Its Offensive1<br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='flag_btn'>flag2 </div>
<div id='flag_cont' style='display:none'>
  <form method='post' class='flag_form'>
    <input type='radio' name='flag_reason' value='off'>Its Offensive2<br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>
</div>
<div class='flag_btn'>flag3 </div>
<div id='flag_cont' style='display:none'>
  <form method='post' class='flag_form'>
    <input type='radio' name='flag_reason' value='off'>Its Offensive3<br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep that was my problem, I forgot to make the button a class.. And using next instead of closest.. Thanks mate cheers!